# Change Text of spark progress bar in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, progress-bar

I think this is easy but get stuck while implementing.
I added progress bar in my project which will show the download process.

I am going to change text of progress bar from `loading 20%` to `Downloading 20%`. I make following changes in my code as i seen somewhere.

```
<mx:ProgressBar mode="manual" labelPlacement="center" label="Downloading 0%" />
```

It will change label to downloading but, not changes percent while process. It remains 0%. 
 I don't know why? where i am wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add event handler to `ProgressBar`: `progress="progressHandler(event)"`.

```
private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percent:int = Math.round(event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100);
    idOfProgressBar.label = "Downloading " + percent + "%";
}
```